# Assign a keymap to a derived mode in emacs

Tags: emacs, mode, keymapping

How can I assign a keymap to a derived mode in emacs (I am using the `define-derived-mode` function). There is a `derived-mode-set-keymap` function but without examples or good documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`define-derived-mode` itself creates a keymap with the name MODE-map, where MODE is the name of the keymap you've just defined.  I'm not sure what `derive-mode-set-keymap` does that is not already done with `define-derived-mode`; looking at the source, they do similar things, and I'm unsure of the very low-level differences between the two (e.g. `define-derived-mode` leaves the parent-mode's keymap as the parent of the new keymap while `derive-mode-set-keymap also merges the keymaps; what's the functional difference between the two?).

If you do the following:

```
(define-derived-mode foobar-mode text-mode "foo")
```

Then the following variables will be defined:

- `foobar-mode-abbrev-table`
- `foobar-mode-hook`
- `foobar-mode-map`
- `foobar-mode-syntax-table`

You can then start manipulating any of these as you like.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Also some other lisp examples using defined-derived-mode make more sens to me now.